# Request Failed for Axios in reactjs with Rails 6 API in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, axios, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using `axios` in `reactjs` which is running on port 3000 & `Rails 6` API application is running in 3001.

I hit for `/authenticate POST` API & checked in the browser network tab for `xhr` tab where I found status as `(cancelled)` and no response or error.

On `rails` log,

```
Started POST "/api/v1/authenticate" for ::1 at 2020-09-04 09:56:49 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::AuthenticationController#authenticate as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"example@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "authentication"=>{"email"=>"example@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here

My `axios` call is like below,

```
  const response = await axios({
    URL: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/authenticate",
    method: "POST",
    data: {"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });
```

I followed [reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) but did not work

src/setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/v1',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3001/',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

API seems right as following return token in response `json` data,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3001/api/v1/authenticate
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using Devise or not, but I use Knock for JWT, which has a nasty habit of requiring a `data` to include `auth` like this:

```js
const response = await axios({
    URL: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/authenticate",
    method: "POST",
    data: {"auth": {"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' }
  });
```

while Devise requires additional header `Accept: application/json`

Refer here -> https://github.com/nsarno/knock#authenticating-from-a-web-or-mobile-application

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/API-Mode-Compatibility-Guide

Don't know if this answers your question though.

Comment: I am going to delete a question as it was a silly mistake from the front end. Axios call was getting canceled due to a button element on which it got called with `onClick` event, had type="submit" which eventually trigger form submit. So I had to change the type.

Comment: If you do not provide `Accept` inside header, it assumes it is `HTML` type and for this request API can render JSON data.